# Issue converting from Swift 2 to Swift 3 in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

So I updated to Xcode 8 and when prompted to convert my source code to Swift 3 I said yes. I forget what I did after that, but for some reason my code is back to the way it was. Now when I try to convert it again, Xcode tells me that i already converted it so I cannot do it again. Is there any way to reset this convert feature or trick it to convert again?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way if you are not using version control. 
Follow this link (
[How to Convert my Swift Code back to 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828700/how-to-convert-my-swift-code-back-to-2-3) ) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is interested I found a workaround. First, create a new project and then copy your source code file(s) into it. Second, hit Edit -> Convert -> To Current Syntax. At that point either stay within the new project or copy your code back to your original project.