# The file “XXX” doesn’t exist

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsfilemanager

I am trying to download a file use  Foreground internet operation . it successfully download but problem is file not exist in the directory

Code :

```
   let urlString = "https://joycemusic1.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/fight-song-rachel_platten.pdf"
        let filePath = "Documents/"

        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString){

            let tast = NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (NSURL, NSURLResponse, NSError) in
                if let error = NSError{
                    print(error)
                }
                if let locationString = NSURL , let fileLocation = locationString.path {

                    //print(fileLocation)

                    let fileExists = NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath("fight-song-rachel_platten.pdf")

                    if fileExists == true{
                       try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtPath(fileLocation, toPath: filePath)
                    }
                }
            })
            tast.resume()
        }
```

download file path is:

> /Users/twilight/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/80CCC33B-817F-46C7-A65E-2B1CAA86D940/data/Containers/Data/Application/43CB754B-4096-47B1-9A97-32D1657E426B/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_EoIzdN.tmp

No file found

[image]

Comment: `NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath("fight-song-rachel_platten.pdf")`. What kind of path is that?

Comment: @vadian thanks for guide line could you help solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two major mistakes.

- You have to check if the file exists at `fileLocation`

  ```
  let fileExists = NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileLocation)
  ```
- The file path `Documents/` doesn't exist at all. You have to get the URL to the documents folder in the sandbox with

  ```
  let documentsURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, 
                                                   in: .userDomainMask, 
                                       appropriateFor: nil, 
                                               create: false)
  ```

  (sorry, that's Swift 3 code)
- Not related to the errors, but after printing the error write `return` to exit the completion block.

**Never** use the class names `NSURL`, `NSURLResponse`, `NSError` as variable names, use `url`, `response`, `error` instead.

Comment: i am using swift 2 . Error Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote *sorry, that's Swift 3 code*. You need to translate it back to Swift 2 or – preferable – update your project to Swift 3

Comment: I could not find anything how can i  back to Swift 2 also i checked this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828700/how-to-convert-my-swift-code-back-to-2-3 . could you give me  some hints

Comment: The easiest way is to retype the method starting with `NSFileManager.defaultManager().url` and use code completion (there are two methods `urlFor` and `urlsFor`. You need the first one). But the best way its to update the project to Swift 3. That's the future.

Comment: thanks i am new in swift should i learn object-c ? please give me  guideline

Comment: No, stay learning Swift. PS: But try to really learn it rather than just copy&paste code without having a clue what it does.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4.0 | Use below code :

- You have to check if the file is present at fileLocation

  ```
  let fileExists : Bool = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileLocation)
  ```
- The file path Documents/ doesn't exist at all. You have to get the URL to the documents folder in the sandbox with

  ```
  let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

  let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileLocation)
  ```